# Migration - Cannot Change Double Data Type Value

Tags: laravel

I have an existing table created with this migration code:

```
Schema::create('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {

 $table->increments('id');
 $table->double('mycolumn',8,2)->unsigned()->default(0);
 $table->timestamps();

});
```

Then I have created another migration file to adjust the value range of my `mycolumn` field with the migration file below.

```
Schema::table('mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {

 $table->double('mycolumn',15,2)->unsigned()->default(0)->change();

});
```

However I am getting an error:

```
In DBALException.php line 283:

  Unknown column type "double" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a li
  st of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgott
  en to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getM
  appedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using

Comment: Laravel version: 5.7

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are missing this from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns)

> Only the following column types can be "changed": **bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger**.

So **double** cannot be changed.

I haven't tried but you can maybe use a RAW MySQL query like this, try it locally first of course:

```
DB::statement('alter table mytable modify mycolumn DOUBLE(15,2) DEFAULT 0');
```

Comment: oh, understood, any suggestion?

Comment: If you don't have any data I would go with deleting the column and creating a new one.

Comment: i just removed the `SET` and it worked as needed, thank you. accepted and upvoted!

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the SET in case someone else needs it.

Comment: what should be handled in `down()` method?

Answer (score 27):

the **double** cannot be changed the way you do for other types, you can fix it using **Doctrine\DBAL\Type**

You can fix it in this way:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\FloatType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

public function up() {
    if (!Type::hasType('double')) {
        Type::addType('double', FloatType::class);
    }
    Schema::table('mytable', function($table) {         
        $table->double('mycolumn',15,2)->default(0)->change();
        .....
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will help, but you may use decimal or float instead of double in this case, though float will not work if you want a limited amount of decimal places.
So it will look like:

```
$table->decimal('mycolumn',15,2)->unsigned()->default(0)->change();
```

Comment: I think this should be the right answer?